# ansible module for EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubectl, amazon-eks

i'm trying to automate deployment in eks cluster using k8s ansible module.
It's seem that k8s module doesn't support EKS.

does anyone have an example of managing objects in eks using k8s ansible module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen this document ? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_eks_cluster_module.html

Comment: yeah, aws_eks_cluster : this ansible module allow to manage cluster (add, delete ... cluster), not manage objects inside cluster (services, deployment, pods ...)

Comment: Hello Chawki, welcome to StackOverflow. I have make some little changes to your question in adding ? character to question, in transforming your title in question because StackOverflow is not a forum but a Question/Answer site and a question is a sentence that ends with a ? character. I have also highlighted product names using `text` characters. I can not help you for the question; I'm only a reviewer.

Comment: Do you have a more specific example of what you're trying to do, and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks everyone, for your comments, it finally works.

I just reconfigure the file `~/.kube/kubeconfig` and set the good config in `~/.aws/`.

Snippet of the Ansible task:

```
- name: "deploy app"
  k8s:
    kubeconfig: "{{ kube_config }}"
    namespace: "default"
    state: "present"
    src: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ data_dir }}/{{ instance_name }}/deployment/deployment_file_1.yml"
    - "{{ data_dir }}/{{ instance_name }}/deployment/deployment_file_2.yml"
    - "{{ data_dir }}/{{ instance_name }}/deployment/deployment_file_3.yml"
```